# react-native-element-dropdown now working properly for android device

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i use the react-native-dropdown-element the scroll of dropdown for multiple value are not working properly for android device but working a iOS devices

Here is my code

```
 <Dropdown
                                style={styles.timeBox}
                                selectedTextProps={{
                                    style: {
                                        color: 'black',
                                    },
                                }}
                                itemTextStyle={{ color: "black" }}
                                data={time}
                                value={endTime}
                                valueField={'id'}
                                labelField={'time'}
                                placeholder='Select Time'
                                onChange={(item) => {
                                    { addMinutes(item.id) }
                                }}
                            />
```

i need a dropdown element and they will be scrollable in android device

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.